# Analyzing diassembled c++ code that crashes

Tags: c++, assembly, c++builder-xe4

The code below crashes when the control leaves '}'. If I replace FieldByName()->AsString with a variable or if I remove the else if that is not executed, it doesn't crash. '==' was replaced by SameText, when the AV started to occur.

```
bool __fastcall TJwsSalesMethods::IsPORequiredForOrderAndCustomer(const String& OrderID, const String& CustomerID)
{
  bool PORequired = false;

  if (IsOrderCustomerPositioned(FqryWork01, CustomerID, OrderID)) // This function executes an SQL statement using FqryWork01->Open()
  {
    //String RequirePO = FqryWork01->FieldByName("RequirePO")->AsString; // Using variable instead will solve
    if (SameText(FqryWork01->FieldByName("RequirePO")->AsString, "Y"))
    {
      PORequired = true; // This block is executed
    }
    else if (SameText(FqryWork01->FieldByName("RequirePO")->AsString, "N"))
    {
      PORequired = false;
    }
    else
    {
      PORequired = IsPORequiredForCustomer(CustomerID);
    }
  } //AV occurs here

  return PORequired;
}
```

Looking at the disassembly,

```
0053a40c       public JwsSalesUtil.cpp.TJwsSalesMethods.IsPORequiredForOrderAndCustomer:  ; function entry point
0053a40c 11784   push    ebp
0053a40d         mov     ebp, esp
0053a40f         add     esp, -$54
0053a412         mov     [ebp-$48], ecx
0053a415         mov     [ebp-$44], edx
0053a418         mov     [ebp-$40], eax
0053a41b         mov     eax, $7cf0e0
0053a420         call    +$18c497 ($6c68bc)     ; __InitExceptBlockLDTC
0053a425 11786   mov     byte ptr [ebp-$49], 0
0053a429 11791   push    dword ptr [ebp-$44]
0053a42c         mov     ecx, [ebp-$48]
0053a42f         xor     edx, edx
0053a431         mov     eax, [ebp-$40]
0053a434         call    -$1ec9d ($51b79c)      ; JwsSalesUtil.cpp.TJwsSalesMethods.IsOrderCustomerPositioned
0053a439         test    al, al
0053a43b         jz      loc_53a586
0053a441 11794   mov     word ptr [ebp-$2c], $c
0053a447         mov     edx, $7c1544           ; 'RequirePO'
0053a44c         lea     eax, [ebp-4]
0053a44f         call    +$18ef14 ($6c9368)     ; System.UnicodeString.Create
0053a454         inc     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a457         mov     edx, [eax]
0053a459         mov     ecx, [ebp-$40]
0053a45c         mov     eax, [ecx+$80]
0053a462         call    +$20285d ($73ccc4)     ; Data.Db.TDataSet.FieldByName (dbrtl180.bpl)
0053a467         mov     [ebp-$50], eax
0053a46a         lea     eax, [ebp-8]
0053a46d         call    -$135786 ($404cec)     ; ustring.h.System.UnicodeString.Create
0053a472         mov     edx, eax
0053a474         inc     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a477         mov     eax, [ebp-$50]
0053a47a         mov     ecx, [eax]
0053a47c         call    dword ptr [ecx+$84]
0053a482         lea     edx, [ebp-8]
0053a485         push    dword ptr [edx]
0053a487         mov     edx, $7c154e
0053a48c         lea     eax, [ebp-$c]
0053a48f         call    +$18eed4 ($6c9368)     ; System.UnicodeString.Create
0053a494         inc     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a497         mov     edx, [eax]
0053a499         pop     eax
0053a49a         call    +$20109d ($73b53c)     ; System.Sysutils.SameText (rtl180.bpl)
0053a49f         push    eax
0053a4a0         dec     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a4a3         lea     eax, [ebp-$c]
0053a4a6         mov     edx, 2
0053a4ab         call    +$18f120 ($6c95d0)     ; System.UnicodeString.Destroy
0053a4b0         dec     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a4b3         lea     eax, [ebp-4]
0053a4b6         mov     edx, 2
0053a4bb         call    +$18f110 ($6c95d0)     ; System.UnicodeString.Destroy
0053a4c0         pop     ecx
0053a4c1         test    cl, cl
0053a4c3         jz      loc_53a4ce
0053a4c5 11796   mov     byte ptr [ebp-$49], 1
0053a4c9 11797   jmp     loc_53a566
```

snip else if and else and continuing from location 53a566

```
0053a566 11806   dec     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a569         lea     eax, [ebp-$14]
0053a56c         mov     edx, 2
0053a571       > call    +$18f05a ($6c95d0)     ; System.UnicodeString.Destroy
0053a576         dec     dword ptr [ebp-$20]
0053a579         lea     eax, [ebp-8]
0053a57c         mov     edx, 2
0053a581         call    +$18f04a ($6c95d0)     ; System.UnicodeString.Destroy
0053a586 11812   mov     al, [ebp-$49]
0053a589         mov     edx, [ebp-$3c]
0053a58c         mov     fs:[0], edx
0053a593 11813   mov     esp, ebp
0053a595         pop     ebp
0053a596         ret
```

The AV occurs where '>' is shown. My question is, why is there 3 creates and only 2 destroys in the first block and in the bottom there are extra 2? So if I total the executed code there are 3 creates and 4 destroys. I also don't seem to know which string corresponds to which Create and Destroy. I can figure out "RequirePO", AsString and "Y" constitutes the three Create and also one of the create points to a different address. Maybe I am not reading it right.

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Mathew Joy

Comment: What are: `String`, `AsString`, and `SameText`?

Comment: I highly doubt that debugging this requires a dump of the assembly code.  Just looking at the code, you're using pointers and assuming that all of them are not NULL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Looking into the assembly was the last resort. There is no new or free. All are created on the stack. My doubt is something is not right. This particular code is tested for years. Re-factoring from == to SameText now causes AV. I also removed one of the checking to make the disassembly simpler.

Comment: @Barry The code is developed in C++ builder now owned by Embarcadero.

Comment: Even if it used for years now, doesn't mean that it is correct. If the stack is corrupted before it, it is undefined behaviour which means it can work for years until you change something unrealted and cause it to crash. Look at the code surrounding it, because this snippet doesn't relly show much and is likely not causing the problem, only exhibiting it.

Comment: What happens if FieldByName() doesn't have the name? You expect it to have always a correct pointer, but is this assumption correct?

Comment: @MathewJoy - "I changed something so tiny, now my program crashes"  Translation:  The program was faulty to begin with and my change finally exposed the bug(s).  If your program has an existing bug, it doesn't mean that the bug will make itself known -- it could be hidden for years, until a simple change in code is done, thus "moving the bug" to a part of the program where it makes a difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Exactly, I wanted to know if any of the Embarcadero's lib causes it. Which is why I pasted the disassembly.

Comment: I understand the points made on debuging etc. I looked into those all. I think I find an anomaly in asm. I might be right, I might not be right.

Comment: Regarding the "extra strings", bear in mind that `SameText` takes its arguments by value; and that `AsString` is actually a Property (therefore, behaving like a function returning a string).

Comment: It'd be fantastic if you could reduce this to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) (also that would increase the chances of them actually fixing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a codegen bug in the compiler to me.  The bit of code at `0x0053a566` is calling `System.UnicodeString.Destroy` with the address of `[ebp-$14]` as an argument.  However, `[ebp-$14]` doesn't seem to have been initialized anywhere.

I'll bet that `[ebp-$14]` will be initialized by a call to `System.UnicodeString.Create` in the stretch of code you elided (that corresponds to the `else if` and `else` clauses) which is jumped around.

Comment: One sensible answer/comment after looking into the asm. There is a bug, and I can reproduce the asm anomaly with the combination of SameText and FieldName->AsString. Most cases it doesn't crash, but the bug anomaly is there. I'll look further. Thanks.

Comment: Micheal, That is the answer. The ini is in the part when I snipped so it deletes something that is not created. Interestingly the second init (in the else if) is destroyed before the first. If I replace with '==' then in the if asm I see three Create and three 
Destroys which I think is the right way. Thank you for helping me with the asm. I just know some rudimentary stuff. I'll log a support case with Embarcadero.

Comment: @MathewJoy can you find the code where `[ebp-$14]` string is supposed to be created? It would shed some light on why the problem has come about.  (This also rings a few bells for me, there have been bugs submitted in the past where AnsiStrings were not created or deleted properly, in conjunction with Property usage)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The `[ebp-$14]` is created in the 'else if' block that I snipped. I can reproduce the asm anomaly with a simple sample project. If I replace SameText with == the Destroy() is within the if and else if blocks otherwise as shown above, it is outside. I opened a QC with Embarcadero.